# ListView not updating after inserting data through an Android DialogBox?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, dialog

hi all Am having listview which displays list of items from sqlite db. Using DialogBox am inserting data in DB. Insertion done successfully. But if i entered data on DialogBox and click ok button, the data inserted in db but the inserted data is not displaying in ListView.

ListView is not refreshing.... I hv used `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);`. But this wont take any effect on listview.

And I have got warning on logcat as

```
`09-16 15:01:10.215: INFO/dalvikvm(2066): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
09-16 15:01:10.215: INFO/dalvikvm(2066): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44c4be28 on PAYMENT_TABLE that has not been deactivated or closed
09-16 15:01:10.215: INFO/dalvikvm(2066):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
09-16 15:01:10.215: INFO/dalvikvm(2066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)`
```

But i hv closed the cursor in OnDestory()

Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);         
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {          
        String mTitleRaw = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_PAYMENT_TYPE));
        al.add(mTitleRaw);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        }    

    adapterChanged();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void adapterChanged() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, al);

    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    listContent = getListView();
    listContent.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mySQLiteAdapter != null) {
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    menu.add(0, MENU_ADD, 0, "Add New");                
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()) {      
    case MENU_ADD:
        AlertMsg();         
        return true;        
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateList(){
    cursor.requery();
    }   

public void AlertMsg() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Payment Type");
    alert.setMessage("Add field");
    final EditText mTxt = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(mTxt);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            String mNewField = mTxt.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item " + mNewField + " Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert(mNewField);
            updateList();

            adapterChanged();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Are this efficient way....

Can anyone pls give some suggestions.....

Thanks......